# Geo points in area

Tags: ios, database, geolocation

I am working on iOS app where at some point I want to get user's location and present her all point of interests on map that are inside a circular area where centre of this area is user's current location and radius is constant. Points of interests are stored in database with their coordinates (latitude, longitude).

I have already managed to get user's location. Now I am trying to figure out how to calculate if certain coordinates are in that area.

I was thinking that I can calculate distance of some point from centre using this equation:

`d = sqrt((centre_latitude - point_latitude)^2 + (centre_longitude - point_longitude)^2)`

Where `d` is distance of that point from circle centre. Then I could simply compare `d` with radius.

I am not sure if this is right and also efficient approach. I can imagine that if I have thousands of points this would be really slow (query database for each point then do the math).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {


float lon= // longitude you want to compare to your current postion
float lat=//your latitude you want to compare to your current position
float rad=//radius , if you give this 100m, then it checks the given points are within the 100m from you are not

CLLocation *centerLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat
                                                        longitude:lon];

CLLocation *lastLocation=[locations lastObject];

//display current lat and lon in text fields
currentLat.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lastLocation.coordinate.latitude];
currentLon.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lastLocation.coordinate.longitude];

CLLocationDistance distance = [lastLocation distanceFromLocation:centerLocation];

if (distance<=rad) {

       // you are within the radius
}

CLLocationAccuracy accuracy = [lastLocation horizontalAccuracy];
if(accuracy <=10) {   //accuracy in metres

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

I have it implemented in Java for Android, maybe it helps you.

```
private static double calculateDistanceInMiles(Location StartP, Location EndP) {  
    //Haversine formula
    //double Radius=6371; // to get distance in kms
    double Radius=3963.1676; //to get distance in miles
    double lat1 = StartP.getLatitude();  
    double lat2 = EndP.getLatitude();  
    double lon1 = StartP.getLongitude();  
    double lon2 = EndP.getLongitude();  
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);  
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);  
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +  
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *  
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));  
    return Radius * c;  
}
```